# segmentation fault when I run C++ code in Embedded device

Tags: c++, tensorrt

I'm using Tensorrt to transform caffe model,and when I running the code in the Embedded device,it prompt segmentation fault.
I have known the problem is at "network->destroy();"，if i comment out of this code,it will not show "segmentation fault".

I have found some methods and try to solve this problem ,but it doesn't work.
Common causes of this problem:
Improper format control string in `printf` or `scanf` statements:
Make sure the format control string has the same number of conversion specifiers (`%'s`) as the `printf` or `scanf` has arguments to be printed or read, respectively, and that the specifiers match the type of variable to be printed or read. This also applies to `fprintf` and `fscanf`.
Forgetting to use "&" on the arguments to scanf:
Function scanf takes as arguments the format control string and the addresses of variables in which it will place the data that it reads in. The "&" (address of) operator is used to supply the address of a variable. It is common to forget to use "&" with each variable in a scanf call. Omitting the "&" can cause a segmentation violation.
Accessing beyond the bounds of an array:
Make sure that you have not violated the bounds of any array you are using; i.e., you have not subscripted the array with a value less than the index of its lowest element or greater than the index of its highest element.
Failure to initialize a pointer before accessing it:
A pointer variable must be assigned a valid address (i.e., appear on the left-hand-side of an assignment) before being accessed (i.e., appearing on the right-hand-side of an assignment). Make sure that you have initialized all pointers to point to a valid area of memory. Proper pointer initialization can be done several ways. Examples are listed below.
Incorrect use of the "&" (address of) and "*" (dereferencing) operators:
Make sure you understand how these operators work. Know when they should be applied and when not to apply them. As mentioned above, it is common to forget to use "&" with each variable in a `scanf` call. Remember, `scanf` requires the address of the variables it is reading in. Especially, know when "&" and "*" are absolutely necessary and when it is better to avoid using them.

this code is use for caffe model to tenserrt model
tenserNet.cpp

```
 builder = createInferBuilder(gLogger);
INetworkDefinition* network = builder->createNetwork();

ICaffeParser* parser = createCaffeParser();
parser->setPluginFactory(NULL);

bool useFp16 = builder->platformHasFastFp16();
//useFp16 = false;

DataType modelDataType = useFp16 ? DataType::kHALF : DataType::kFLOAT;

/** Debugging Notes
 *  1. The datatype is taken by the code.
 *  2. The network is properly defined here. A network is created here.
 *  3. There is some error with the deploy file.
 *  4. parser used here is nvCaffeParser.
 *  5. blobNameToTensor also has some name.
 * */
// const IBlobNameToTensor* blobNameToTensor =  parser->parse(deployFile.c_str(),
//                                                           modelFile.c_str(),
//                                                           *network,
//                                                           DataType::kFLOAT);
const IBlobNameToTensor* blobNameToTensor = parser->parse(deployFile.c_str(),
                                                          modelFile.c_str(),
                                                          *network,
                                                          modelDataType);

assert(blobNameToTensor != nullptr);

for (auto& s : outputs) network->markOutput(*blobNameToTensor->find(s.c_str()));
builder->setMaxBatchSize(maxBatchSize);
builder->setMaxWorkspaceSize(16 << 20);
//IRuntime* infer;
infer = createInferRuntime(gLogger);
if(useFp16)
{
    builder->setHalf2Mode(true);
}

engine = builder->buildCudaEngine( *network );
assert(engine);

context = engine->createExecutionContext();
assert(context);

network->destroy();
parser->destroy();

//gieModelStream = engine->serialize();
// engine->destroy();
// builder->destroy();
// pluginFactory.destroyPlugin();
// shutdownProtobufLibrary();
context->setProfiler(&gProfiler);
// context->setProfiler(nullptr);
CUDA_VERIFY(cudaStreamCreate(&stream));
```

NvInfer.h

```
class INetworkDefinition
{
    // ...
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~INetworkDefinition() {}
};
```

Comment: Generally free or destroy resources in the opposite order you allocate or create them. And make sure allocations and creations succeed, by having null-pointer checks (and `assert` is not enough).